# Rails + Passenger bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I am getting this error on my production app which I still has no clue of fixing it. The app works fine on development mode, but I get a bundler error on my production server. I am using an ubuntu server with ruby 1.9.3 via RVM + Nginx + Passenger. Any help is much appreciated.

```
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

bundle install
If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

Is this app supposed to be run as the ubuntu user?
Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
Please check whether the correct RVM gemset is being used.
Sometimes, RVM gemsets may be broken. Try resetting them.
-------- The exception is as follows: -------

Could not find chronic-0.10.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:348:in `running_bundler'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:243:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
Application root
/home/ubuntu/websites/tracker-console
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
production
Ruby interpreter command
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/wrappers/ruby
User and groups
uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu) groups=1000(ubuntu),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),110(netdev)
Environment variables
rvm_bin_path = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545
TERM = xterm-256color
SHELL = /bin/bash
IRBRC = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/.irbrc
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXrRxB97
SERVER_PORT = 80
MY_RUBY_HOME = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545
USER = ubuntu
DOCUMENT_ROOT = /home/ubuntu/websites/tracker-console/public
SCGI = 1
_system_type = Linux
REQUEST_URI = /
rvm_path = /home/ubuntu/.rvm
IN_PASSENGER = 1
RACK_ENV = production
REMOTE_PORT = 54600
rvm_prefix = /home/ubuntu
PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@taxi-tracker-console/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:/opt/nginx/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
WSGI_ENV = production
PWD = /home/ubuntu/websites/tracker-console
LANG = en_US.UTF-8
NODE_PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/node_lib
_system_arch = x86_64
NODE_ENV = production
_system_version = 13.10
REMOTE_ADDR = 123.231.122.121
rvm_version = 1.25.22 (stable)
SERVER_NAME = console.tracker.lk
HOME = /home/ubuntu
SHLVL = 0
RAILS_ENV = production
rvm_ruby_string = ruby-1.9.3-p545
SERVER_SOFTWARE = nginx/1.4.7
LOGNAME = ubuntu
QUERY_STRING = 
SERVER_ADDR = 10.128.193.224
GEM_PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
rvm_delete_flag = 0
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
RUBY_VERSION = ruby-1.9.3-p545
_system_name = Ubuntu
_ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global
Ulimits
Unknown
System memory usage
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1651        827        824          0         17        213
-/+ buffers/cache:        596       1055
Swap:          895         79        816
General Ruby interpreter information
RUBY_VERSION = 1.9.3
RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 2.2.2
Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
DESTDIR = 
MAJOR = 1
MINOR = 9
TEENY = 1
PATCHLEVEL = 545
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
EXEEXT = 
prefix = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545
ruby_install_name = ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
exec = exec
ruby_pc = ruby-1.9.pc
PACKAGE = ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
MANTYPE = doc
NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
vendorhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/include/ruby-1.9.1/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/include/ruby-1.9.1/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/include/ruby-1.9.1
UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
configure_args =  '--prefix=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545' '--disable-install-doc' '--enable-shared'
vendordir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitedir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby
ruby_version = 1.9.1
sitearch = x86_64-linux
arch = x86_64-linux
RI_BASE_NAME = ri
ridir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/ri
rubylibprefix = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby
MAKEFILES = Makefile
PLATFORM_DIR = 
THREAD_MODEL = pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
EXPORT_PREFIX = 
COMMON_HEADERS = 
COMMON_MACROS = 
COMMON_LIBS = 
MAINLIBS = 
ENABLE_SHARED = yes
DLDLIBS =  -lc
SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -L/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -lruby
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -L/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBYARG = -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -L/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -lruby
LIBRUBY = libruby.so.1.9.1
LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so.1.9 libruby.so
LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.1.9.1
LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
rubyw_install_name = 
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.9
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED = gcc -shared
EXTDLDFLAGS = 
warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
debugflags = -ggdb
optflags = -O3
cxxflags =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cflags =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cppflags = 
NULLCMD = :
INSTALLDOC = nodoc
CAPITARGET = nodoc
RDOCTARGET = nodoc
EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
ARCHFILE = 
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
EXTOUT = .ext
PREP = miniruby
TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
setup = Setup
EXTSTATIC = 
STRIP = strip -S -x
TRY_LINK = 
LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG =  -Wl,-R%1$-s
LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%1$-s
LINK_SO = 
LIBEXT = a
DLEXT2 = 
DLEXT = so
LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
LDSHARED = gcc -shared
CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
STATIC = 
ARCH_FLAG = 
DLDFLAGS = 
ALLOCA = 
codesign = 
POSTLINK = :
WERRORFLAG = -Werror
CHDIR = cd -P
RMALL = rm -fr
RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
CP = cp
RM = rm -f
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
DOXYGEN = 
DOT = 
MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA = /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/bin/install -c
SET_MAKE = 
LN_S = ln -s
NM = nm
DLLWRAP = 
WINDRES = 
OBJCOPY = :
OBJDUMP = objdump
ASFLAGS = 
AS = as
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
try_header = 
COUTFLAG = -o 
OUTFLAG = -o 
CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
GNU_LD = yes
GCC = yes
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
GREP = /bin/grep
CPP = gcc -E
CXXFLAGS =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
CXX = g++
OBJEXT = o
CPPFLAGS =   
LDFLAGS = -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
CFLAGS =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC
CC = gcc
target_os = linux
target_vendor = unknown
target_cpu = x86_64
target = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
host_os = linux-gnu
host_vendor = unknown
host_cpu = x86_64
host = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
build_os = linux-gnu
build_vendor = unknown
build_cpu = x86_64
build = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE = 2014-02-24
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 1.9.3
BASERUBY = ruby
target_alias = 
host_alias = 
build_alias = 
LIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
ECHO_T = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_C = 
DEFS = 
mandir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/man
localedir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/locale
libdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib
psdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
pdfdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
dvidir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
htmldir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
infodir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/info
docdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
oldincludedir = /usr/include
includedir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/include
localstatedir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/var
sharedstatedir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/com
sysconfdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/etc
datadir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share
datarootdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share
libexecdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/libexec
sbindir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/sbin
bindir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin
exec_prefix = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545
PACKAGE_URL = 
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
PACKAGE_STRING = 
PACKAGE_VERSION = 
PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
PACKAGE_NAME = 
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
SHELL = /bin/bash
rubylibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1
archdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
sitelibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
sitearchdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
vendorlibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
vendorarchdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
topdir = /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
Activated Ruby gems
bundler => 1.6.1
Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)
enumerator.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/compatibility.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/errors.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/thread.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/etc.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/buildout/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/socket.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpdir.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/analytics_logger.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/constants.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/io/console.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/version.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/settings.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/digest.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ftp.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/https.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldap.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldaps.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/mailto.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/request.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/core.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/cookie.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/uri_formatter.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/bn.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/cipher.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/config.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/digest.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/x509-internal.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/securerandom.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/text.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/ruby_version.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/ui.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/ui/silent.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/environment.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/index.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundler is missing gem chronic-0.10.2

Add chronic gem in your gem file

```
 gem 'chronic', '0.10.2'
```

or manually install as follows

```
 gem install chronic --version 0.10.2
```